# How to create a chaining or cyclic sequence with a list in Python, so that after the last index of a list we can start from first index again

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have an alphabets list:

```
alpha_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

For a given alphabet(considering it will always be present in alpha_list) I want to get an alphabet whose index is garter by a given number, consider below function for example:

```
def get_replacing_letter(alphabet, number):
    index = alpha_list.index(alphabet)
    return alpha_list[index + number]
```

`get_replacing_letter('a', 2)` will give me 'c'

what I want is `get_replacing_letter('d', 2)` should give 'a'
similarly `get_replacing_letter('e', 2)` should give 'b'

So the `alph_list` should work in a chaining sequence or cyclic manner. I am wondering how to achieve this in Python?

Answer (score 1):

You can make new index take the modulo of the length of the list:

```
return alpha_list[(index + number) % len(alpha_list)]
```

Comment: Thanks, it's prefect.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment I achieved it by extending the alpha_list with itself:

```
alpha_list.extend(alpha_list)
```

This way as index method gives first index of occurance, I could manage to get it working.

However I am wondering if there is any better way to achieve this.